# Clearing the cache of an asp.net web application does not work as expected

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching

I have an asp.net web application (vb.net) that includes certain pages where the user enters sensitive data. Once the page is submitted, I really do not want the user to be able to hit the Back button and go back to the same page with the data prefilled.

I read several posts about how to disable the Back button, and most say that best practice is to leave the Back button alone and rather clear the cache by setting the appropriate cache headers. So in the Master pages of my application I have included the following page headers:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store"/>
```

However the application still allows the user to see all the form data entered in the above scenario (after submitting the form and then hitting the back button). What else do I need to do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

handling the ViewState of the form should be a solution

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_viewstate.asp

Comment: Are you suggesting that I disable the view state? I cannot do that, because upon form submission I will lose all the data entered... I only want the page cleared when I hit the Back button, not in a regular Postback cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to the browser cache (like you mentioned) but not so much the store used when you close your browser and come back; I've dealt this before and it seems to be treated like an in-memory type cache - odd behavior, I know. Usually hitting back will fill inputs exactly as they were - you can tell because the page renders nearly instantly since it's not doing any server work.

As a workaround, you can always clear inputs using javascript when the page loads. This will always run (even when rendering from cache)

Answer (score 0):

The first response I received was not really useful in my case, since I had to retain the viewstate and not disable it.

So instead I tried the javascript workaround suggested in the second response. I do not clear the inputs per se, but I have javascript code that runs with every page load. It compares the initial values of some variables (that get initialized from the server when the page is first loaded), to their current values as saved in cookies. If there is a discrepancy, then I give the user an error message and force them to redirect to a specific page.

The code looks something like this:

```
    var originalID = '<%= GetMyID() %>';
    var cookieID = getCookie('MyID');

    if (cookieID!= originalID) {
        showMessage();
    }
```

Ideally I would still prefer to be able to invalidate the cache when the back button is hit, but I still don’t see how I can do that.